# solving equations with powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Im trying to solve the equation $$3\cdot2^{-2/x} + 2\cdot9 ^{-1/x}  = 5\cdot6^{-1/x }$$ So far I tried applying logaritmas but it didnt prove helpful...are there any other ways?

Comment: First step: replace $1/x$ with a new variable $u$ and solve for $u$. Second: extract a factor of $3$ from each term. I'm not sure where this will lead you, but at least it's a start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $9=3^2$ the equation becomes

$$3\times 2^{-2/x}+2\times 3^{-2/x}=5\times2^{-1/x}3^{-1/x}$$
so let $a=2^{-1/x}$ and $b=3^{-1/x}$ then we have

$$3a(a-b)+2b(b-a)=0\iff(a-b)(3a-2b)=0$$
and since $a\ne b$ then $3a-2b=0$ hence
$$\frac a2=\frac b3\iff2^{-1/x-1}=3^{-1/x-1}\iff\left(\frac1x+1\right)(\ln3-\ln2)=0\iff x=-1$$

Comment: nice approach, many thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Set $2^{-\frac{1}{x}} = a, \ 3^{-\frac{1}{x}} = b$ so the equation becomes $3 a^2 + 2 b^2 -5 ab = 0$.